# IOS7 Tableview autolayout not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, constraints, autolayout

Oh, I am having trouble with AutoLayout in IB(xcode 5, ios7), an IPad project.

Here is a view hierarchy in my project.

```
UIViewController->UIView->UITableView->UITableviewCell->UILabel。
```

And I add some constraints to UILable, (1.pin height, 2. Pin leading space to superview 3.pin trailing space to super view, 6 pin top space to superview.). But when I look in the portrait mode, I think it should change its' width to keep 2 and 3 constraints, but it didn't, can anyone give me a suggestion what should I do.

Thanks a lot!

Here is my screen shot in portrait mode and landscape mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your constraints in IB?

Comment: Are the table view and its cells changing their size properly when you rotate?

Comment: I have add screenshot and the cells seems change their size when i rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I'm right when I say that you obtain the second screenshot when you select `Landscape` for the `Orientation` in the `Simulated Metrics` of your view controller. As the title of this section suggests, it's a simulation (might be different at run time). The warning message you have might be saying `Frame for **** will be different at run time.` Have you tried to run your app? Have your labels wrong positions/sizes ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried to run my app, the label has right position. Can you tell me why I selected landscape in the Simulated Metrics will give me the warning message?

Comment: Well, I'm experiencing same issue as you for cells. In the rest of my app, when I simulate landscape mode, subviews are resized to match the constraints, but not in cells. I have no explanation for this. For the warning message, Xcode is just informing you that your label is not at the right place on your IB according to the constraints, and it will be displayed differently when running.